# Why is my html/php/ajax not returning any rows from my query?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have been working on this for the past two days, and it is the only part of the assignment that is giving me trouble. 
I thought AJAX would make it so the results of the PHP page would be displayed on the original page. (this is how it worked on the previous page I worked on. However, that one only needed to return one result, so copy+pasting that code will not work here).

I need the results from the myName_search.php file to show up on the html file once I click the button, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Would using json help? Here is a screenshot if it helps you understand what is going on:

[image: here is a screenshot if it helps you understand what is going on]

The HTML File is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function queryStudent() {
        //Retrieve user input, minGPA
        var minGPA = document.getElementById('input').value

        //Build querystring
        var queryString = "?minGPA=" + minGPA;

        //Create XMLHttpRequest
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                //Define function to process server feedback
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xmlhttpRequest.responseText;
            }
        };
        //Run query
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "myName_search.php" + queryString, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script> 
</head>
    <body>
        <article>
        <form name="student" method="post"  action="myName_search.php">
        <label>Minimum GPA: </label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="4" id="input" name="minGPA" value="">
        <br>
        <br>
            <input type="button"  onclick="queryStudent();"     value="Search" id="button">
        </form>
        <p>Students with higher than minimum GPA will be displayed below.</p><br>

        <!--output section after search-->

        <section id="output">
        <h2>Student list (Students with GPAs higher than <?php echo ($minGPA); ?></h2>

        </section><br><br>
        <a href="search_split.htm">Search & Split</a>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PHP file is

```
<?php

require("database.php");

//Retrieve user input 
$minGPA = $_REQUEST['minGPA'];

//Evaluate user input
if( $minGPA == "" )
    die("Invalid GPA");

//Prepare and execute
$sql = 'SELECT studentID, name, email, GPA FROM student WHERE GPA >= :minGPA ORDER BY studentID';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(':minGPA', $minGPA, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$students = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>StudentID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>GPA</th>

    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($students as $student) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $student['studentID']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $student['GPA'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Thank you for all of your help, I found the problem

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
           document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.responseText; 
};
```

Comment: Check the Network tab of the browser to see if an error is being returned.

Comment: Not related to the problem: You should take the `<h2>` outside the `<section>` so it doesn't get overwritten with the results.

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("POST",` probably needs to use a GET

Comment: no errors show up in the network tab. Thank you for the recommendation, though.

Comment: @Gerard I edited it to see if that would work, and it didn't change anything. Good catch though. It might help later.

Comment: `document.getElementById('input')` does not give you anything unless you add `id="input"` to the HTML input element. I would suggest using a different name for the ID.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all of your help, I finally found the problem